# I'm having a hard time managing to get hair to sprout symmetrically

Tags: hair

therefore I'm having a hard time getting hair to comb symmetrically, etc. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I'm literally just adding the emitter modifier in the particle settings from a mesh, switching to hair for the emission, and still it comes out jittered. I can get it to come out of the vertices, but even after symmetrizing the mesh, the hair still comes out just a touch lopsided. While I'm still kind of self-teaching some of the basic functions of Blender (Version 2.92) I'm getting turned off of this mechanic as it is...

Answer (score 0):

The trick to get good hair done is to create several hair group zone spots.
ea multiple hair particle systems.
So you take a system for each side, left/right front, back, and sometimes extra zones. then you can camb per zone without affecting the other hair.

Comment: That's...not really what I need? Granted that's probably good advanced for someone who's more advanced in their experience with blender than I, but the problem is I've seen and heard people getting a scalp hair emitter to miraculously spit out evenly on but the left and right sides of the mesh in such a way that the mirror tool actually works. Not me though. I just need to know what settings to flip on to get my hair particles to emit symmetrically so I can quickly bush both sides into an even shape to avoid more chaotic hair physics.

Comment: using one emiter for all a persons hair really makes it a hard job to work on, using several zones eases it a lot, i've been strugeling like you as well in the past, thinking it can be done, although not impossible it can be done so much easier with zones of particle system, thats the easy road to good looking hair https://youtu.be/vu6MQC6qdRY